# Debo agregar "Coordenadas" en forma de string a una matriz

Tags: python, string, lista, bucle-for, while

Contextualizando un poco, sigo creando mi buscaminas, el que debe generar matrices (En ese caso "dimensiones" de tablero) de manera aleatoria, pero como seria un poco extenso pondré una matriz ya establecida. El que debe rellenarse con minas creadas aleatoriamente (pero pondré unas establecidas para facilitar)

```
tablero_minas = [["A",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 ["B",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 ["C",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 ["D",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 ["E",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 ["F",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 ["G",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 ["H",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 ["I",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 ["J",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 ["K",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
             

string_minas = "D9C1A10F10E11E3A2" #D9 C1 A10 F10 E11 E3 A2

posicion = 0
while posicion <len(string_minas):
    letra = string_minas[posicion]
    for i in range(len(tablero_minas)):
        if letra in tablero_minas[i]:
        fila=i
        columna = int(string_minas[posicion+1])
        tablero_minas[fila][columna]=10
    posicion =posicion+2
print(tablero_minas)


#Aqui lo que imprime
#[['A', 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 #['B', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 #['C', 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 #['D', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0], 
 #['E', 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 #['F', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 #['G', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 #['H', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 #['I', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 #['J', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 #['K', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Tengo una matriz (Variable Tablero), de 11x11 el que debe rellenarse con un 10 (cualquier entero en realidad) si es que corresponde a la posición de una mina (las que deben estar escritas en forma de string), escribí este código para que lea el string como coordenadas, pero tiene errores, SOLO lee el primer dígito después de la letra (coordenadas como E11, F10 las lee como E1 F1), y a veces las coordenadas finales no las lee.

Estoy abierto a cualquier recomendación, para mejorar el código, a crear alguna función o re - escribirlo

En resumen debo leer un string, interpretarlo como coordenada y "añadira" al tablero.

Todo es bienvenido

Comment: Estás aumentando de 2 en 2 y tienes algunas direcciones que ocupan 3 caracteres. Por ahí va tu problema. De paso, estás enumerando las posiciones comenzando en 1 (hasta 11) pero el array va a tener posiciones de 0 a 10. Eso va a ser un problema una vez resuelvas el problema anterior.

Comment: ok, gracias por el consejo!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma correcta de recuperar las coordenadas es usando expresiones regulares, pero eso es un tema más avanzado, por lo que usare un enfoque más básico.

La idea es definir la función `extrae_coord` que saca una coordenada desde el string, buscando a partir de la posición que le das. No tiene ninguna validación, asi que espera que las coordenadas esten bien escritas.

Este deberìa ser tu tecnica habitual cuando enfrentas una dificultad (extraer coord en este caso): define una función separada que resuelva el problema sin polucionar el cuerpo central del codigo.

Supongo que las columnas se numeran desde 1 en adelante (no existe la coord. A0). Si no es el caso, lo puedes arreglar.

Intente conservar la mayor parte de tu código. Obviamente, hay varias cosas que se pueden optimizar. Quedan de tarea.

```
tablero_minas = [["A",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 ["B",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 ["C",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 ["D",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 ["E",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 ["F",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 ["G",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 ["H",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 ["I",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 ["J",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 ["K",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
             

string_minas = "D9C1A10F10E11E3A2" #D9 C1 A10 F10 E11 E3 A2

def extrae_coord(string, pos):
    """ Extrae una coordena desde el string.
        La coordenada empieza con una letra y sigue un
        numero variable de digitos.
     
        Retorna: la coordenada y la posicion de la sig. coord.
    """
    index = pos + 1
    while index < len(string) and string[index].isdigit():
        index +=1
    return string[pos:index], index

posicion = 0
while posicion < len(string_minas):
    coord, posicion = extrae_coord(string_minas, posicion)
    
    letra = coord[0]
    for i in range(len(tablero_minas)):
        if letra in tablero_minas[i]:
            fila=i
            columna = int(coord[1:])
            tablero_minas[fila][columna]=10


for fila in tablero_minas:
    print(fila)
```

Produce:

```
['A', 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0]
['B', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
['C', 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
['D', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0]
['E', 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10]
['F', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0]
['G', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
['H', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
['I', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
['J', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
['K', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: un millón de gracias!!!, voy a probarlo en seguida!!

Comment: Candid Moe, una consulta, al generar la nueva matriz, la genera con un espacio después de la coma y antes del carácter o numero.¿Hay alguna forma que la genere sin espacios?

Comment: @MartinSilva. Sólo tienes que reemplazar la última línea (`print (fila)`) por otro que imprima cada línea en el formato sin espacios.